# Shiny : Get the selected radio's button selected value

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get the selected radio button in a shiny script. This is not as simple as that because I am creating the radio button in the server part. I had to do this because the name of the radio button comes from a database. And now, I need to return what value is selected in the sever part.
Here is my code : ui.R

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
    dateInput("date", h3("Choose a date:"), value = as.Date("2016-01-17")),
    uiOutput("choose_columns"),
    checkboxInput("legend", "Show legend", TRUE)
    )
  )
```

And here the server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
         user="root", password="",
         dbname="shiny", host="localhost")

    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM file,date WHERE date.IdDate=file.dateId AND date.date=\"17-01-2016\"")
    data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
    mylist=list()
    for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    mylist<-append(mylist,setNames(list(data[i,3]),data[i,3]))
    }       

  # Check boxes
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    # Get the data set with the appropriate name
    #dat <- get(input$date)
    #colnames <- names(dat)
    rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM file,date WHERE date.IdDate=file.dateId AND date.date=\"17-01-2016\"")
    data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
    mylist=list()
    for(i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    mylist<-append(mylist,setNames(list(data[i,3]),data[i,3]))
    }

    # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
     radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Variable"),
        choices = mylist,selected = 1)
  })
```

Comment: It's still going to be `input$radio` in your `server.R` file.

Comment: print(input$choose_columns) returns me NULL

Comment: `input$radio`, not `choose_columns`, which is an output variable. Also, printing can go a little wonky in Shiny; I find it's usually more useful to use `verbatimTextOutput` and `renderText`.